# Why is clearing a List using setState not working for clearing my ListView as well?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code for populating a list which I use for a ListView

```
List<dynamic> menuItemList =[];

  Future<void> displayItems() async {
    // I recently tried setState here after trying it onTap() of menu option
    setState(() {
      menuItemList.clear();
    });
 
    var getMenuIDs =
        await _dbRef.child('Categories/$categoryPath').onValue.listen((event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        //fetching all available records in orderTracker
        var data = event.snapshot.value as Map;

        //adding records to list
        data.entries.map((e) => itemIDList.add(e.value)).toList();

        //cycling through the list and extracting the orderID
        var listLength = itemIDList.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
          var listItem = itemIDList[i].toString();
          itemID = listItem.substring(9, 12);
          // trackerID = listItem.substring(12, 15);

          allMenuDetail(itemID);
        }

      } else {
        //Empty
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> allMenuDetail(String itemID) async {
//List will be empty here
    _streamSubscriber =
        await _dbRef.child('MenuItem/$itemID').onValue.listen((event) {
//For some reason it repopulates here
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        var data = event.snapshot.value as Map;

        var price = data['price'];
        var itemName = data['itemName'];
        var desc = data['description'];
        var itemImg = data['img'];
        var item = data['id'];

        Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
          'price': price,
          'itemName': itemName,
          'desc': desc,
          'img': itemImg,
          'itemID': itemID
        };
        List<dynamic> shortList = [myMap];
        menuItemList.addAll(shortList);
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        print('*********************=> HERE ');
      }
    });
  }
```

I then display the menu item as follows:

```
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: menuItemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = menuItemList[index];
              var price = item['price'];
              var itemName = item['itemName'];
              var desc = item['desc'];
              var itemImg = item['img'];
              var itemID = item['itemID'];
           
              return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ItemPageState(
                            // path: categoryPath,
                            itemName: itemName,
                            desc: desc,
                            price: price,
                            itemImg: itemImg,
                            id: itemID)));
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          ClipRect(
                              child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            widthFactor: 0.8,
                            child: Image(
                              image: AssetImage(itemImg),
                              height: 100,
                              width: 150,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          )),
                          const SizedBox(width: 30),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                itemName,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Price: R' +
                                    price.toString(), //+ price.toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 30),
                        ]),
                  ));
            },
          )
```

I have a menu at the top of my page which will used to navigate to different categories of food. Once one of the icons is clicked I am able to fetch the relevant menu items but the list doesn't clear properly. I have use prints and it says the list has been emptied but on the GUI it just adds the other menu items at the bottom of the one first loaded

this is my menu code

```
        Container(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.separated(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                separatorBuilder: (context, _) => const SizedBox(
                      width: 12,
                    ),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: categoryMenuList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final catItem = categoryMenuList[index];
                  var catIgm = catItem['img'];
                  var title = catItem['title'];
                  var path = catItem['path'];
                  return Container(
                    width: 95,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    child: Material(
                                        child: Ink.image(
                                      image: AssetImage(catIgm),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          //I did try set state here as well
                                          categoryPath = path;
                                          pageTitle = title;
                                          displayItems();
                                          setState(() {});
                                          refreshPage();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ))))),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 4,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
```

Sorry for the long winded post but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

Comment: just use menuItemList.clear(); without setstate.

Comment: This still gives me the same issue. The list the says its clear but the card on my page don't clear. Instead the new card are being added underneath. Is there a way to refresh the listViewBuilder

Comment: I edited to show that the list repopulates after the _streamSubscirber onValue(). Not sure why

Comment: where do you call allMenuDetail?

Comment: I fixed it. allMenuDetail is called at the end of displayItems

Comment: I fixed my problem. The issue was I was not emptying the itemIDList that I was using to cycle through to extract IDs. This caused all the ones that had previously been called to be passed on again to allMenuDetail